# MS Access Modern chart - plot series on secondary Y Axis

Tags: ms-access, charts, ms-access-2016

I have an MS Access Modern Chart in a Form. It contains two series of data; one with values up in the thousands, and the other with most values below 10. I therefore need to put one of those series onto a secondary Y axis on the chart.

Previously I have edited modern charts using the 'Chart settings' window that appears on the right when a modern chart is selected. However, in this case the Row source is entered by VBA (rather than basing the chart on a query) so no Series formatting options show in the chart settings window.
I cannot base the chart on a query as I need it to respond to changes in a combobox on the same form (the chart's row source is manipulated by VBA linked to `On_change` event of the combo box).

How do I move one of my chart's series to the secondary axis? Is there a chart property I've missed? Is it something I can do within the chart's Row Source property/sql?

Comment: I can't use Modern Chart but I have used classic MSGraph with an SQL statement as chart RowSource that references a control on form for dynamic display of data with a WHERE clause. Can't you do that with Modern Chart? If you use VBA to manipulate RowSource, then set it with an SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you @June7, that is exactly what I'm doing with Modern Chart (sorry I should have made that clearer, see edits) - however my question is about adding a secondary Y axis.